# Ethereum nonce behaviour on invalid transaction

Tags: ethereum, go-ethereum

Given the state:

1. Account X, nonce: 0
2. Account X sends a valid TX
3. Account X new nonce: 1
4. Account X sends an **invalid** TX that doesn't pass a validateTx() check in mempool (msg too large, more than 32kb for example)
5. Account X new nonce in the global state: **2 or 1** ?

If an account sends in invalid TX should the nonce of the next transaction be the same as of the invalid one or does it have to increase after every attept to submit a TX?